# change the location of android virtual devices

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Ive tried all the possible ways I have come across to change the location of where the avds are located, but nothing. The location in preferences is spot on and no matter what, the location stays the same. Ive also added a new path and restarted eclipse after doing so, changed folders, but still nothing, I dont know what am doing wrong